# Show the space X is incomplete

Tags: convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences

A problem comes from the "*Optimization by vector space methods*". Luenberger p.34

Let $X$ be
1. the space of continuous functions on [0,1]
2. its norm is defined by $||x|| = \int^1_0|x(t)| dt$
So, 
1. $X$ is a normed linear space.

To show $X$ is incomplete, it define a sequence of elements in $X$ by the equation:

[image]

with the graph:

[image]

At first, it proves that the sequence is Cauchy since $||x_n - x_m || = \frac {1}2|1/n -1/m|\rightarrow 0$

And it says, there is no continuous function to which the sequence converges.

My questions are
1. How to obtain $\frac {1}2|1/n -1/m|$
2. What does the last sentence mean?
3. How to see the completeness depends critically on the definition of norm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. $\int_0^{1/2} x_n dt$  is just the area of a triangle with base $\frac{1}{n}$ and height $1$
2. Short way: assume $x_n\rightarrow g$ in your ($L^1$) norm, and assume $x_n\rightarrow h$ pointwise (you should be able to explicitly write out this $h$), then we must have $h = g $ a.e. (why?). So is $h$ continuous? If not continuous, can we remove the discontinuity by modifying $h$ on a measure zero set?
3. A normed ( or metric) space $X$ is complete if every Cauchy sequence is convergent in $X$. Here the norm (or metric) determines whether $x_n$ is Cauchy or not, so with the $\max$  norm, the $x_n$ in the problem is not a Cauchy sequence.

**Edit:** Let me say more about (2), to say $x_n \rightarrow g$ in your norm, it means that 
$$\lim_n \int_0^1 |x_n - g| dt = 0.$$
Now you will see that $x_n$ converges pointwise to $\chi_{[\frac{1}{2}, 1]}$. By Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, we have
$$0 = \lim_n \int_0^1 |x_n - g| dt = \int_0^1 \lim_n |x_n - g| dt = \int_0^1 |\chi_{[\frac{1}{2}, 1]}-g| dt = \int_0^\frac{1}{2} |0-g| dt + \int_\frac{1}{2}^1 |1-g| dt.$$
If $g$ is continuous, then both $|0-g|$ and $|1-g|$ are nonnegative continuous functions, what can you say about them if you know their integrals are zero.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

(1) You can calculate the norm doing the integral.

(2) *What* function *can* be the limit?

(3) With the $\sup$ norm the space is complete.

Comment: To (2), the limit would be a step function, which is not continuous. Is it true?  However to (3), the reason for incompleteness lies in the discontinuous, which is not related to the def. of norm?

Comment: With regard to (2): Saying what it *looks* like it can be isn't enough. saying "the limit can only be function $f$" isn't very satisfying, how do you know this is the only limit, etc. (unless of course you were implying to prove this).

Comment: @sleevechen, (2): is true, but more technical detail is required. (3): the reason for incompleteness lies in the **inexistence** of some **member of the space** (in *this* case $X=C([0,1])$) that be the limit of the Cauchy sequence. With the $\sup$ norm the sequence *isn't* Cauchy.

Answer (score 2):

$\|x_n-x_m\|$ mean:

$$\|x_n-x_m\|=\int_{0}^{1}|x_n(t)-x_m(t)|dt$$

Let $n \leq m$ (case $n \geq m$ is symmetric), then when $t \in [0,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}]\cup [\frac{1}{2},1]$ you have $x_m(t)=x_n(t)$, so:

$$\|x_n-x_m\|=\int_{0}^{1}|x_n(t)-x_m(t)|dt=\int_{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{2}}|x_n(t)-x_m(t)|dt$$

You probably can prove that $\|x_n-x_m\|=|1/n-1/m|$, but it's easier when we note:

$$\|x_n-x_m\| \leq 1$$

So:

$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{2}}|x_n(t)-x_m(t)|dt \leq \int_{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{2}}1dt=\frac{1}{n}$$

It's proof that $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

But we see that $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=x$, where $x(t)=0$ when $t \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $x(t)=1$ when $t \in [\frac{1}{2},1]$. But $x$ isb't continous function, so X is incomplete.